# Using bash to copy every 2nd line from one document to the beginning of every 2nd line of another

Tags: bash

I am trying to copy every second line from one document to the start of every second line of another document. Kind of like this:

```
Document 1
1
2
3
4
5
6


Document 2
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Becomes:

```
Document 3
a
2b
c
4d
e
6f
```

The actual document has much more data though. So far I am able to export every second line from document 1:

```
sed -n '2~2p' document1.txt
```

But I don't know how to then copy it to the start of every second line of document 2. Can somebody please put me in right direction to accomplishing this?
Thank you

Comment: Note that the `2~2` notation is not standard; it is a GNU `sed` extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more portable version of TenG's solution:

```
sed <f1 'g;n' | paste -d '\0' - f2
```

- `g` - replace pattern space with (empty) hold
- `n` - print pattern space then replace with next line and implicitly print that
- `-d '\0'` - paste uses `\0` to mean "don't insert a delimiter" not as <kbd>NUL</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, this is a really simple but effective solution - Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Given f1 is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Given f2 is:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Let's blank the odd lines in f1:

```
sed '1~2s/^./ /' f1 > f1a
```

Now f1a is:

```
.
2

4

6
```

Now, our very old but forgotten friend `paste`

`paste -d':' f1a f2` gives:

```
 :a
2:b
 :c
4:d
 :e
6:f
```

Take out the spaces/delimiters:

```
paste -d':' f1a f2 | sed 's/^ //' | sed 's/://'

a
2b
c
4d
e
6f
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler just to do: `sed <f1 '1~2s/.*//' | paste -d '' - f2` ?

Comment: Since the data is more complex than shown in the question, the substitute command probably needs to be more like `1~2s/.*//` (replace everything with nothing).  You then don't need the `sed 's/^ //'` phase; you could simply do the `sed 's/://'` operation.  This just leaves you hoping that the even lines in the first file never contain a colon — you could arrange to use another character (maybe a control character like `^A`, control-A) instead of a colon.  The two `sed` commands could/should be combined: `sed -e 's/^ //' -e 's/://'` or `sed 's/^ //; s/://'` depending on your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

A short awk program:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR    {if (NR % 2 == 0) d1[FNR] = $0; next} 
    FNR % 2 == 0 {$0 = d1[FNR] $0} 
    1
' document1.txt document2.txt
```